# What to do when I found a question that I need an answer to but that has no answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945706/java-bufferstrategy-graphics-or-integer-array)  that is several years old yet has no answers. However, I would like to see a true answer to the question and feel that it will benefit many other people, (there are several comments but no solid answer with thorough testing) and am unsure as to what to do. I thought of reposting the question but am afraid of getting down voted for duplicate question (even if I acknowledged the existence of the old question!). What is the standard thing to do in this situation? And BTW I do not have enough rep to set bounties.

My question is also similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) (which is sort of ironic) with one major difference: the old question I want an answer to was not posted by me, which seems to be all that the above link is about.

Comment: A bounty was generously placed on that question, which brings it back into focus. Unfortunately, there are currently **43** featured Java questions, so there still is some competition.

Comment: Just to note, I took the plunge and added an answer to the best of my abilities.